# slapd 2.4.23 hangs on ldaps connections

Tags: ssl, openldap, tls, slapd

New install of CentOS 6.3, openldap-servers-2.4.23. Generated a new certificate request, signed the cert, started slapd. ldapsearch responds on ldapi:/// and ldap:///. However, as soon as a request is made on ldaps:///, the slapd process consumes all available CPU and never responds.

strace -p  -ff yields the following results, in an infinite loop:

```
[pid  5978] open("/etc/openldap/certs/server.key", O_RDONLY) = 21
[pid  5978] stat("/etc/openldap/certs/server.key", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=1704, ...}) = 0
[pid  5978] read(21, "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIE"..., 1704) = 1704
[pid  5978] close(21)                   = 0
[pid  5978] open("/etc/openldap/certs/server.key", O_RDONLY) = 21
[pid  5978] stat("/etc/openldap/certs/server.key", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=1704, ...}) = 0
[pid  5978] read(21, "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIE"..., 1704) = 1704
[pid  5978] close(21)                   = 0
[pid  5978] open("/etc/openldap/certs/server.key", O_RDONLY) = 21
[pid  5978] stat("/etc/openldap/certs/server.key", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=1704, ...}) = 0
[pid  5978] read(21, "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIE"..., 1704) = 1704
[pid  5978] close(21)                   = 0
[pid  5978] open("/etc/openldap/certs/server.key", O_RDONLY) = 21
[pid  5978] stat("/etc/openldap/certs/server.key", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=1704, ...}) = 0
[pid  5978] read(21, "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIE"..., 1704) = 1704
[pid  5978] close(21)                   = 0
[pid  5978] open("/etc/openldap/certs/server.key", O_RDONLY) = 21
[pid  5978] stat("/etc/openldap/certs/server.key", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=1704, ...}) = 0
[pid  5978] read(21, "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIE"..., 1704) = 1704
[pid  5978] close(21)
```

I've re-generated certs just to be sure they aren't corrupt, no joy.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Apparently openldap loads the certs differently depending on where they are in the directory structure. If they are in the /etc/openldap/certs dir - it treats them as MozNSS and afterwards fails spectacularly to load anything at all. If they are in /etc/pki, it uses OpenSSL and loads everything just fine.